# Not able to test connection pooling in glassfish server with java

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish

I am using a `glassfish 4.1` server with `java 8`.

I have created a `JDBC connection pool` and attached this pool to `JDBC Resources.`

I have also put `jdbc14.jar` file to domainRoot/lib folder.

I am try to monitor it but in monitor section that's come blank.

So my question is how to get number of open/Active connection or idle connection.Basically I just want know how to test connection pool working successfully or not.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically I just want know how to test connection pool working
>   successfully or not.

To test this just go to your new Connection Pool in the Glassfish Admin UI and click on the `Ping` button. If it says "Ping Succeeded" then everything should work.

For Monitoring details you have to enable the Monitoring.

Go to `server-config` -> `Monitoring` and set the level for `JDBC Connection Pool` to `HIGH`.

To get some details you have to actually use the pool at least once, to do this it should be sufficient to ping it again. Then go to `server (Admin server)` -> `Monitor` -> `Resources` to see the details.